# Function Series in Sympy

Tags: function, sympy, series

I am quite new to sympy. I need to work with Function Series, something of the kind,

`Sum(f_i(x), (i,0,n))`

Of course this could be written like Sum(f(x,i),(i,0,n)) having defined i and n as integer.
Anyway, I am not finding any online resource to learn how to work with this conveniently, write the series, and then make operations like derivatives,...

Could anybody recommend a resource, or explain how she/he is writing it in sympy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could add a typical example of the type of series you want to represent and explain the manipulations and algorithms you want to let loose on them?

Comment: This would be of interest to me as well. Last time I used `summation` I had to write my own derivative operators ([link](https://github.com/wsdookadr/so/blob/master/so-65707040/recurrence-coeffs.ipynb)) . Maybe I missed some of the documentation and SymPy already has this implemented.

Comment: @JohanC f_i(x) are generic functions, of yet unknown form. Their first and second derivatives should be applied as well as products with other series. The final product should be collected as a tensor dependent of x.